# Extjs 4.1 window.close() does not destroy it

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I create an object of window, and put tabpanel in this window. but window.close() method does not destroy window. When I click button to open window again it display 2 different tabpanel, one from old window and another from new window and it crash my user interface.

I also called listener "beforeclose" and in this method destroy tabpanel but that doest not work.

What can be done?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that [closeAction](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-closeAction) option is set to `destroy`?
Of course it is a good idea to show simplified sources, so we can understand where the problem exists.

Answer (score 2):

Add closeAction:'destroy' to your window. It should work.